# Proving the existence of analytic continuing of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a real smooth function (infinitely differentiable) on $[0,1]$ and suppose that there exists some $C>0$ such that the maximum absolute value of every $n$th derivative of $f$ is smaller than $C^{n+1}n!$ on $[0,1]$.

I need to show that there exists a domain $G$ which includes $[0,1]$ such that there is an analytic function $g$ on $G$ which equals $f$ on $[0,1]$.

The material we've studied so far was up to Cauchy's formula and Cauchy's Integral theorem, though I read a little bit further on Taylor series but I guess they expect us to use what we've studied.

Any direction?

Comment: There is an explicit formula for the radius of convergence of a power series, it will give what you want.

Comment: I know the formula, how does that help me though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $|f^{(n)}(x)| < C^{n+1}n!$ for all $x\in [0, 1]$ guarantees that for each $a \in [0, 1]$, $f(x)$ is equal to its Taylor series at $x=a$:
$$
 f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n
$$
for $x \in [0, 1]$, $|x - a| < \frac 1C$. (Use e.g. Taylor's theorem with the [Lagrange remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder).)

That Taylor series has a radius of convergence of (at least) $1/C$. If we define
$$
 g_a(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (z-a)^n
$$
then $g_a$ is analytic in the disc $U_a = B_{1/C}(a)$, and equal to
$f$ in $U_a \cap [0, 1]$.

Now cover the interval $[0, 1]$ by finitely many such disk $U_a$, and define $g$ in the union $G$ of those disks as
$$
 g(z) = g_a(z) \text{ if } z \in U_a \, .
$$
Use the identity theorem to show that $g$ is unambiguously defined, and equal to $f$ on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: You seem to have spotted the error before seeing my explanation of what was wrong - very good.

Answer (score 1):

Various answers and comments point out that the Taylor series has a positive radius of convergence, which is clear, and then say we're done. No, that's not enough.

**Example** Define $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ by $$f(t)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/t^2},&(t\ne0),
\\0,&(t=0).\end{cases}$$This is a standard example; it's well known that $f$ is in fact infinitely differentiable on the line, and that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for every $n$. So the Taylor series centered at the origin has *infinite* radius of convergence. But $f$ certainly does not extend to a holomorphic function in a neighborhood of the origin. The "extension"  given by those other answers is identically zero, which is not an extension at all.

To give a correct solution: Say $a\in[0,1]$, and consider the Taylor series centered at $a$. You need to show that if $|a-t|<1/C$ then the series converges to $f(t)$.

Not just that it converges, which is all you get from the radius of convergence; it has to converge to $f(t)$. This is easy from Taylor's Theorem, with, say, the Lagrange form of  the remainder. Look up "Taylor's Theorem"  on Wikipedia...

Regarding "I guess they expect us to use what we've studied": I gather  this is a class in complex analysis. Hence "they" expect you to know *calculus* already, and Taylor's Theorem is part of any decent calculus class.

**But** in fact calculus students never know Taylor's Theorem! I suppose there may be counterexamples, but I've never seen one - every calculus student I've ever seen who *thinks*  he or she knows Taylor's Theorem thinks it's this:

> > **NOT Taylor's Theorem.** If $f$ is infinitely differentiable near $a$ then $f(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(t-a)^n$ near $a$.

That's not Taylor's Theorem, and in fact the example above shows that it's *false*.

Comment: Thank you very much! Both you and Martin helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The inequality guarantees that the Taylor series of $f$ converges on the unit disk. That's your extension.

Comment: I don't yet see where the convergence on the unit disk comes from. Couldn't $f$ be analytic just in a neighborhood of the interval? Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: Just knowing that the Taylor series converges is not enough.